# High voltage high frequency clipper

Tags: voltage-clipping

I want to measure the frequency of a  signal around 200khz (max) and the voltage may vary from 10v to 200v peak-peak. I will have only a constant voltage at the time of measurement. Not varying.

So the approach I am trying to use is to feed the AC signal to a simple ultrafast diode clipper circuit to limit the voltages via a huge current limiting resistor of 100k and then feed it to a F-V convertor ADVFC32.

Will this approach work?

Comment: It will but be aware of phase delay that might be introduced from the resistor and parasitic (or intentionally added) capacitances. The phase delay might not matter depending on what you are doing with it.

Comment: You say AC, but you also say that you "will have only a constant voltage at the time of measurement", so I'm curious as to what your signal actually looks like

Comment: What I meant was it will be a fixed voltage AC is either 10 VAC or 30 VAC or 150 VAC or 200 VAC. But it will not be like a gaussian wave. That was what I meant